# jQuery UI & Content Editable in Modal dialogs

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog, contenteditable

Are there any issues surrounding the use of contenteditable div elements in jQuery UI that lead to the caret not appearing.  Here is a bit of code to show what I mean

```
<div id='diaHTMLEd' style='display:none'>
  <div id='divRTE'></div>
  <!--iframe src='xrte.html' height='300' width='500'></iframe-->
</div>

function openHTMLEditor( {
    $('#diaHTMLEd').dialog({
        height:200,
        width:450,
        modal:true,
        open:addRTE
    });
}

function addRTE() {
    $('#divRTE').html("<div contenteditable='true'>Testing</div>");
    return;
}
```

Explanation - I am opening up a modal jqUI dialog and in its :open event am adding a contenteditable div element to an inner div in the dialog.  The text shows up but it does not become editable when clicked.  If I replace that code and use the commented out iframe instead which contains an contenteditable drive everything works just fine.

It looks like there is something that stops content from becoming editable inside the dialog.

This question may be lacking in some detail but given the complexity of my application I am not really in a position to provide more representative code.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A note for anyone running into this thread.  After much work I eventually discovered the issue.  Using contenteditable with jQuery UI dialogs is not by itself a problem.  The problem in my case came down to some sort of conflict with the excellent jstree plugin which I am using.

As a general rule - in complex applications that use multiple plugins you are probably better off sandboxing contenteditable content inside an iframe